# Bloomberg Short Cuts in EXCEL

Tags: excel, bloomberg

Is there a method to remove or at least disable Bloomberg keyboard short cuts in Excel?

For example, normally to open a filter I can press CONTROL + SHIFT + L. However, this shortcut is now being used in Bloomberg and it causes my Excel to either freeze or not load for some time.

Comment: Maybe this can help (https://superuser.com/a/212632)...

Comment: http://wallst.training/resources/Bloomberg%20CapIQ%20FactSet%20Disable%20Hotkeys.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following code in VBA:

```
Public Sub DisableBloomberg()    
    Application.OnKey "+^l"    
End Sub
```

This should disable them, if you are lucky :)
[Here you can read more about `Application.OnKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-onkey-method-excel).

If you do not know what VBA is, then in Excel do the following:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
3. Write `Application.OnKey "+^l"` to the opened window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: @OPM_OK - that's a pity. But try a few times, in theory it should work.

Comment: I will. Thanks anyways, Ill come back and let u know if it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Bloomberg tab in the workbook, select **Options -> Hot Key Manager** and disable Bloomberg hotkey (top right corner)